# How to manage loginViewControllers in an app programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Firebase to create a mini social media. There are currently two components, a loginRegisterViewController, which handles login and registration, and a TabbarViewcontroler, which presents the main content.

In appDelegate's didFinishLaunching method, i set the TabbarViewcontroler as the rootView controller

```
let rootviewController = TabbarController()
window?.rootViewController = rootviewController
```

and in the TabbarController's viewDidLoad method, i implement the following code to see if a LoginViewController should be presented or not.

```
class TabbarController: UITabBarController {

var handle : FIRAuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    // check if the user is logged in or not.
    handle = FIRAuth.auth()!.addStateDidChangeListener(){ auth, user in
        if user == nil {
            self.present(loginRegisterViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            self.setupTabbarController()
        }
    }

   }
}
```

If the user is logged in, we setup the tabbarViewController, if the user is not, we present the loginRegisterViewController on top of the tabbarViewController.

However, every time I register a new user and dismiss the loginRegisterViewController, I will get an empty tabbarViewController.

I understand that this happens because of the if-else condition in the viewDidLoad method of the tabbarViewController.

Since initially there is no user logged in, the

```
self.setupTabbarController()
```

method is thus not called.. Therefore, after i register a new user and dismiss the loginRegisterViewController, i get an empty tabbarViewController.

But, how do I go to solve this? Or is there a better way of checking if a user is logged in or not to present the mainContentViewController or LoginRegisterViewController?

Thanks in advance.

Edit : The setupTabbarViewController is a function to setup the tabbarController

```
  func setupTabbarController(){

    let shopControler = ViewController()
    let shopNavigationControler = UINavigationController(rootViewController: shopControler)
    shopNavigationControler.tabBarItem.title = "Shop"
    shopNavigationControler.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Shop_Tabbar_Image")

    viewControllers = [newsfeedNavigationControler, shopNavigationControler]
}
```

Comment: what does your setupTabBarController function look like?

Comment: @JustinM， just typical way of setting up a tabbarControlelr, the main problem is that it is not called... I included in the post already

Comment: would you mind editing your original question and adding the code formatted properly. That length of code is not easily readable in comment.

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned correctly we would need to call `self.setupTabbarController()` again, after the login state changes.

I usually go with this kind of implementation:

Create a class `AuthManager` or something like that. This has the users loginState and a function called `configureRootViewController`.
Declare a static sharedInstance.

In the AppDelegate - `didFinishLaunchWithOptions`:
Your call would look something lie this:
`AuthManager.sharedInstance.configureRootViewController()`

All that configureRootViewController() does is it checks the login state and configures the correct rootViewController.

Every time your login state changes you want to call this method again.

I hope that helped. Still rather early to give precise answers. :-)
Have a great day.

Comment: hi @florianthompson... I am wondering if it is possible for you to be a bit clearer on how i implement this? Not so proficient with IOS.. Thanks a bunch!